# How do I map over data from API in a collapsible table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if the question captures what I had in my but I will explain below...
I fetched data from API and mapped into a collapsible table. Full details of the data should be embedded in EACH row such that onclick on each row, reveals the full details. Here's the code below

```
 function Encounter() {
  

  const [open2, setOpen2] = useState(false);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

  const getDetails = async () => {
    try {
      const fetch = await Axios.get(
        "https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/all/encounter"
      );
      setDetails(fetch.data.data)
     
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDetails();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      
     
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell/>
              <TableCell >
                Enrollment ID
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell >
                Encounter
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                Facility Code
              </TableCell>
             
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {details.map((detail, idx) => {
              return (
                <>
                <TableRow sx={{ "& > *": { borderBottom: "unset" } }}>
                  <TableCell>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="expand row"
                      size="small"
                      onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                    >
                      {open ? (
                        <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
                      ) : (
                        <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
                      )}
                    </IconButton>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={idx}>
                    {detail.enrollment_id}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={idx}>
                    {detail.encounter}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={idx}>
                    {detail.faciity_code}
                  </TableCell>
                  
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
              <TableCell
                style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }}
                colSpan={6}
              >
                <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                  <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                      Details
                    </Typography>
                    <Tooltip />
                  </Box>
                </Collapse>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            </>
              );
            })}

            
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
     
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Encounter;
```

The problem I have is how to implement the open and setOpen state to individual row, also the Tooltip component(which is a the full table details from the API)  to display full details of each row onclick which should correspond to the selected row in question.

Comment: Are you using Material-UI ?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. I suggest making a new question for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions to the first problem.

**1. Create a separate component for each `<TableRow />`**

This component will have its own state and allows you to collapse/expand each row individually.

**2. Use a dictionary for the open state**

Since you have multiple (dynamic) rows, you can introduce a dictionary for the `open` state.

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState({});
```

For each row, you will use the `open[idx]` property to determine if the row should be "open"

```js
<Collapse in={open[idx]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
```

And in the `<IconButton />` component, set the state based on the current row state.

```js
<IconButton
  aria-label="expand row"
  size="small"
  onClick={() => setOpen(current => ({ ...current, [idx]: !current[idx] }))}
>
```

Comment: Thank you Chris.  It worked. For the second question, each table row should also contain same data but embedded in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add a variable in your details object:

```
const getDetails = async () => {
    try {
      const fetch = await Axios.get(
        "https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/all/encounter"
      );
      
      const response = fetch.data.data;
      response.map((elem) => elem.open = false)
      setDetails(response)
     
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Then you can change the `open` variable for each element in details:

```
<IconButton
   aria-label="expand row"
   size="small"
   onClick={() => detail.open = !detail.open)}
>
```

You might need to update the state, so change your `onClick`:

```
onClick={() => changeOpenStatus(idx))}
```

and the function:

```
const changeOpenStatus = (idx) => {
    const newDetails = {...details}
    newDetails[idx].open = !newDetails[idx].open;
    setDetails(newDetails)
}
```